# apache virtualhost configuration

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

im trying to create a virtualhost on my dev environment.

basically, i want

- 192.168.1.1 = load /var/www/web1
- 192.168.1.1/web2 = should load /var/www/web2

i thought it'd be simple enough to just create 2 sets of configuration file under 
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and then just change the values as so..

**web1**

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin some@email.com
            ServerName 192.168.1.1
            DocumentRoot /var/www/web1
    ...
    </Directory>
```

**web2**

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin some@email.com
            ServerName 192.168.1.1
            DocumentRoot /var/www/web2
    ...
    </Directory>
```

upon testing this config. `192.168.1.1` loads `/var/www/web1`, which is the way i want it to be. but `192.168.1.1/web2` wont seem to load `/var/www/web2`.

can someone assist how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

You should either go for [name](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-name-based-virtualhost-example/) based virtual hosting or [IP](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html) based virtual hosting.